# Client doesn't receive SSE messages

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, server-sent-events

I am writing web application for quizes and have stucked on a problem with SSEs. I have the following code on kotlin written:

@GetMapping(value = ["/id/{id}/subscribe"])
fun subscribeToSession(@PathVariable id: String) =
subscriptionService.subscribe(id, SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE), subscribers)

@Service
class SubscriptionService {
fun subscribe(id: String, subscriber: SseEmitter,
subscribers: MutableMap<String, MutableSet>): SseEmitter {
subscribers.putIfAbsent(id, hashSetOf())
subscribers[id]!!.add(subscriber)
return subscriber
}

```
fun notifySubscribers(id: String, eventName: String, obj: Any,
                      subscribers: MutableMap<String, MutableSet<SseEmitter>>) {
    subscribers[id]!!.forEach { subscriber ->
        subscriber.send(SseEmitter.event().name(eventName).data(obj))
        subscriber.onError{ error ->
            subscribers[id]!!.remove(subscriber)
            subscriber.completeWithError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

and the following code on react:

useEffect(() => {
updateStates();
const eventSource = new EventSource(`/api/sessions/id/${contestId}/subscribe`);
eventSource.onmessage =  event => {
console.log("f23432545")
updateStates();
};
console.log(eventSource)
return () => {
eventSource.close();
};

}, []);

After some time spent I found out that server does sent a message to client (notifySubscribers works fine), but clent doesn't react on it.

Can some of you tell me where is the problem?